# Why isn't my reusable d3.js chart showing a chart?

Tags: d3.js, charts, data-visualization

The chart appears as a blank white chart; I know it's there because when I generate the chart the page adjusts to fit the chart. The difference is there is no axes or chart data.

I'm trying to implement a reusable d3.js chart but I cannot get it to work; here is the reusable chart code:

```
function chart() {
    var margin = {top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 75};
    var width  = 400 - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;

    var xScale = d3.time.scale();     // time series
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear();   // our float/int data points
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis();
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis();
    var vline = d3.svg.line();        // our data will use this line
    var varea = d3.svg.area();        // our data will fill this area

    function my(selection) {
        selection.each(function(data) {
            xScale
                .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return parseDate(d.x); }))
                .range([0, width]);

            yScale
                .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })])
                .range([height,0]);

            xAxis
                .scale(xScale)
                .orient("bottom")
                .ticks(12)
                .innerTickSize(-height)
                .outerTickSize(-height)
                .tickPadding(3);

            yAxis
                .scale(yScale)
                .orient("left")
                .ticks(6)
                .innerTickSize(-width)
                .outerTickSize(-width)
                .tickPadding(3)
                .tickFormat(d3.format(",d"));

            vline
                .x(function(d) { return xScale(parseDate(d.x)); })
                .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); });

            varea
                .x(function(d) { return xScale(parseDate(d.x)); })
                .y0(height)
                .y1(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); });

            // add SVG
            var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg").data([data]);

            // make chart if it doesnt exist
            var gEnter = svg.enter().append("svg").append("g");
            gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "x axis");
            gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "y axis");
            gEnter.append("g").attr("path", "line");
            gEnter.append("g").attr("path", "area");

            svg
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

            var g = svg.select("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

            g.select(".x.axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis)
                .selectAll("text")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "rotate(-65)";
                });

            g.select(".y.axis")
                .call(yAxis);

            g.select(".line")
                .attr("d", vline(data));

            // draw area
            g.select(".area")
                .attr("d", varea(data));
        });
    }

    return my;
}
```

I am calling the chart like this:

```
myData = [
  { 'x': "2015-11-19 17:37:31", 'y': 0 },
  ...
];

var c = chart();
d3.select("#blah").data(myData).call(c);
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/auvdn4gh/5/

fixed one: https://jsfiddle.net/auvdn4gh/11/

Comment: You probably want `d3.select("#blah").datum(myData).call(c);`.

Comment: Also use `var svg = d3.select(this).append("svg");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few reasons.

**1.** In the JSFiddle you provided, there is no html tag with the class `.service`, so when you calculate that width, it has no idea what you're referencing. So width is being calculated as 0 - 20 - 75 = -95. A chart with a negative width isn't going to show up.

So I first fixed that by just setting `width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right`

**2.** In your `xAxis` and `yAxis`, you gave the ticks enormous values of

```
    .innerTickSize(-height)
    .outerTickSize(-height)
```

and

```
    .innerTickSize(-width)
    .outerTickSize(-width)
```

So you had the ticks stretching across the entire graph, blacking it all out. So I removed those.

Now your graph is showing up: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crclayton/auvdn4gh/7/)

Comment: That's exactly right. You're not appending any `path` for the line or for the area. You're just appending `g` and assigning them a class of `line` or `area` and not doing anything with them. Where did you get this "reusable code" because it doesn't seem reusable to me. I think you should start over from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245)